# asp.net and OpenLayers4: Cannot read property '0' of null inside popup control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress, openlayers

i'm developing a website that deals with maps using asp.net, c# and openlayers4. The map code is written in a separate page `map.aspx`. I display this page inside an`ASPxPopupControl` in `buildings.aspx` main page. In the map page i call methods that zoom to a certain point x,y. The code has been successfully performed for weeks. Now the code gives me this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null  at ol.js:442
at Bn.k.qm (ol.js:442)
at Bn.b (ol.js:46)
at Bn.Sc.b (ol.js:49)
at Yc (ol.js:51)
at Bn.k.set (ol.js:51)
at Bn.k.We (ol.js:442)
```

This is how I call `ol` : `<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>`

The line of code causing the error

```
overlay.setPosition(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:28191', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

where `overlay` is

```
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
   var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
        element: container,
        autoPan: true,
        autoPanAnimation: {
            duration: 250
        }
    });
```

When I run the code from `map.aspx` page it works successfully, but it fails if the page where displayed inside an`ASPxPopupControl`. As i said before the code was working using the `ASPxPopupControl`.

Comment: If it has suddenly stopped working it may be something unusual or invalid in the current data.  Changing ol.js to ol-debug.js probably won't fix it but may give you more information about where the error is occurring,

Comment: Put `console.log(coordinate.toString());` in front of `overlay.setPosition(...);` so you can see what was passed to cause the error.  You may have a missing or invalid value in your data.